# non-DB backend for Django Apps

Tags: python, django, mod-python

I'm trying to integrate `wsgi` Python app into a `Django` app as a controller - The App will provide the output and input (eg. as a dictionary) and send the data to view/controller.

I do not need a DB backend because the commands will be run on the go through `wsgi` and the output won't be stored in a DB.

What is the best approach to accomplish this goal? Is it `Django` suitable for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this will help you.... http://www.librador.com/2011/05/23/How-to-run-Django-tests-without-a-database/

Comment: You can use Django without a database, but there isn't much point. Flask will probably be a better fit for you.